# How to solve SyntaxError when running Flask web server?

Tags: flask, ipython

When I run this command:

```
FLASK_APP=web.py flask run
```

I get this error:

```
File "<ipython-input-2-26c34e6a35fe>", line 1
    FLASK_APP=web.py flask run
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I missing?

Comment: i think you should first do ```export FLASK_APP=web.py``` then run ```flask run```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be running a terminal command inside `ipython` based on the error message.

The problem with this is that you haven't told ipython that you're trying to run a terminal command.

> In Jupyter Notebook you can execute Terminal commands in the notebook cells by prepending an exclamation point/bang(!) to the beginning of the command.

[source](https://anaconda.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023858254-Executing-Terminal-Commands-in-Jupyter-Notebooks)

So do this instead:

```
!FLASK_APP=web.py flask run
```